# Declaring hex on python

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

im pretty new on python and sorry for my broken english.
I have some experience with c/Arduino programing but now im trying to learn to work on raspberrypi and python scripts can you guys help me out.
In arduino im declaring it as

```
#define adrram 0x00
#define adrtemp 0x03
```

and  in python

```
adrram = [0x00]
adrtemp = [0x03]
```

but the data sent through serial ar incorect.

A corect way to put that data in the program

Comment: YOu want a byte string: `b'\x00\x03'`

Comment: Please show us how you are USING these.

Comment: If you are new to python, best is to pick up a book to learn the basic data types, including [Python List](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to use these variables directly, what you did was set a list because of the square brackets. From my understanding, this is what you might have intended:

```
adrram = 0x00
adrtemp = 0x03
# No more square brackets to set it to a number variable instead of a list
```

if this isn't what you are looking for please add more context to your question.